# Set element negative "left" position exactly it's width using CSS3

Tags: html, animation, css

I'm hiding an inline-block element inside of a parent `div` with `overflow:hidden`. I am then offsetting the original child element using the `left` property (negative), so it is hidden. I can make it reveal itself back into the parent using CSS3 transitions, but I'm having to give that negative offset a fairly large number (the width of the parent div), making the timing depend on how much text there is. I need it to be perfect (for reasons not explained here). It would be perfect if the `left` value always matched the width value of the inline-block element.

**Is there any way to find the width of an inline-block element and apply that value to its left offset in CSS3?**

I have a feeling I'm going to have to use jQuery, I'm just hoping someone here might have a wonderful solution. :)

Example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/RD7Yv/1/

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/RD7Yv/4/

Comment: Yes! Somehow I thought the 100% would be the parent element's width. I don't know how I've missed this. Thanks!

Comment: @thirtydot,AlexKempton Actually, it is! That's why thirtydot wrapped the elements. Very nice fiddle btw!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `left:-100%`, This should work.

EDIT:
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ravaE/)

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't really help but the answer is what I needed, cheers. Also credit to thirtydot for his perfect example in the comments!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to "reveal itself back into the parent using CSS3 transitions", it seems like it would be easier to not move the element at all and just animate it's visibility in place.  For example, here's animating it's opacity:

http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/BqmQK/

All, we use JS for is to add/remove a class from the element and CSS3 does an opacity animation for us.  This way the element can be left it it's original position and we don't have to do any size or position calculations.

This same animation can even be done with no javascript if it is triggered by hover.

If you want to see the image sliding into place, then you can set it's initial position to:

```
left: -100%;
```

and animate it to:

```
left: 0;
```

You can see that working here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/P2H4Z/

Comment: Thanks for the input but it's the slide effect I'm really after. :)

Comment: @AlexKempton - what side effect?

Comment: @AlexKempton - I added another option to see the sliding transitioning between `left: -100%` and `left: 0`.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, I now have a sliding option too.  It wasn't clear from the question that sliding was a requirement.  It just said "reveal itself using transitions" so I offered the simplest way to do that.  But, now that the OP has clarified they want sliding, I've added sliding with a full working jsFiddle.